# Twilio REST BindingResource Error "Could not match service instance to account"

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to create a new BindingResource for FCM but it returns

"Could not match service instance to account"

This is my code

```
var binding = BindingResource.Create(
  pathServiceSid: "ISXXXXservice_sid",
  identity: TwilioHelper.Identity,
  bindingType: BindingResource.BindingTypeEnum.Fcm, 
  address: this.ApiClient.IAuth.GetDeviceToken()
);
```

What I understand is that my ServiceSID (Programmable Chat Service) is not registered or does not exists in our Account, but this is not true. I am pretty sure, that my ServiceSID does exists and correct.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using test credentials when making this API request?

Comment: @philnash we are using production credentials

Comment: Ah, I think I know what it is. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Chat Bindings documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/bindings-resource) says the following:

> Bindings for Programmable Chat are **created and updated by the chat client SDKs**, with the ability to list, inspect and remove bindings being offered through the REST API.

My guess here is that you are using the [Twilio Notify Binding resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/binding-resource) which can be accessed from the REST API but requires a [Notify service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/service-resource) and you're giving it a [Chat service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/services).

As the documentation states though, this should be handled through the client SDKs.

Comment: ok so the mistake I did was, I am taking the Programmable Chat service ID instead of Notify Service ID --- They both have "IS" prefix!! Why is that not included in your SDK docs? https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/binding-resource :( Been battling with that for 3 days :(

Comment: I've raised this with the documentation team. Sorry this got you stumped.

Comment: regarding the "address" property, should that be the deviceToken registration from firebase device token id?

Comment: how do you exactly create a Binding in ProgrammableChat? I tried creating one, but it was Notification

Comment: In Android (which I'm guessing you're using right now with FCM) you call `registerFCMToken` from the client. Check out the docs here: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/4.0.0/docs/classcom_1_1twilio_1_1chat_1_1ChatClient.html#a39fe1a3b50b9a9f869f22010258df15f